# Elementary proof.

Tags: terminology

What actually elementary proof means ?

If there is an elementary proof for a conjecture , then is it a theorem ?

I saw papers on some conjectures proving stating as elementary proof. Then it means the conjecture is proved ?

Is there any site that correctly tells about status of a conjecture ?
thanks in advance .

Comment: The search for "elementary proof" on Google returns [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_proof) as the first result, which seems to answer your question.

Comment: An elementary proof is just a proof that is elementary. You just need to pick up a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elementary proof" can mean several things:
1.  A proof that doesn't use big machinery;
2.  A proof that is short and sweet;
3.  A proof by a crackpot claiming to have solved some famous conjecture;
4.  A proof that is too fiddly to write down, so the author says it is "elementary" so that he/she doesn't need to spend time figuring out a good way to write it properly;
5.  A proof that everyone in the field is aware of, but has never been written down, so if you are new to the field you don't have a chance of figuring it out.

Item (4) is more usually denoted "it is clear that..."  And (5) is more usually denoted "it is well known that..."

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that when we say elementary proof we mean a proof which doesn't use techniques from seemingly more complicated mathematics theories.

For example, a proof of the Prime Number Theorem --- which is a statement about $\mathbb{N}$ primarily --- that uses complex analysis is not considered elementary.

Answer (score 2):

Elementary proof is a proof which uses some basic mathematical tools, rudiments of mathematics etc. Please also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_proof